# bootstrap под 1920px

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Прислали макет адаптивной верстки, с разрешением декстопа под `1920px`

Не получается правильно задать настройки bootstrap перед компиляцией и скачкой, чтобы классы `.container` `.col-lg-*` были под `1920px`, `col-md-*` - `1200px` и т.д.

Помогите пожалуйста правильно расставить тут настройки: [ссылка](http://getbootstrap.ru/docs/3.3.7/customize/)

Comment: Я использую бутстрап 4 вместе с небольшим css файлом для bootstrap 4 для верстки под большие разрешение, 1600, 1920, 2560.
Вот статья с репозиторием на файлы [Bootstrap 4 Grid для больших разрешений экранов](https://onlinebd.ru/blog/bootstrap-4-grid-dlya-bolshikh-rezreshenii-ekranov)

Answer (score 2):

Это для col-lg и col-md. Переходите на секцию "Медиа запросы и точки пребывания"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это для container. Переходите на секцию "Размеры container"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте заполнить как на картинке.